# Redirect paste event into iframe using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iframe, paste

At the moment i am trying to "catch" the paste event that may occur within a web project using JavaScript in order to process the pasted content. As widely known (and discussed may times on stackoverflow) this is not really possible without hacks.

Therefore i am using the hack to set the selection to a different (contenteditable) element before paste, get the content and restore the selection afterwards. This works quite well as you can see here:

```js
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
  var target = document.getElementById('el2');

  while (target.lastChild) {
    target.removeChild(target.lastChild);
  }

  var selection = window.getSelection();

  var newRange = document.createRange();
  newRange.setStart(target, 0);
  newRange.setEnd(target, 0);

  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(newRange);

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(target.innerHTML);
  }, 1);
}, true);
```

```css
#el1, #el2 {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
  height:200px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="el1" contenteditable="true">Paste here</div>
<div id="el2" contenteditable="true">Should go here and be logged</div>
```

The problem is that in may case the pasted content often contains CSS styles (paste from office or web pages) and this causes the style of the web project to be destroyed.

To work around the problem i tried to redirect the paste into a iframe. Using an iframe would separate the pasted style from the style of the web project and the problem would be solved.

But as soon as i set the selection to the iframe the example doesn't work anymore. Here another example (will not work if you run the code here as one part of the html belongs into the iframe):

```js
document.addEventListener('paste', function(e) {
  var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
  var iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow;
  var iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument;

  var target = iframeDoc.getElementById('el2');

  iframeWin.focus();

  var selection = iframeWin.getSelection();

  var newRange = iframeDoc.createRange();
  newRange.setStart(target, 0);
  newRange.setEnd(target, 0);

  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(newRange);

  window.setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(target.innerHTML);
  }, 1);
}, true);
```

```css
#el1 {
  border:1px solid black;
  padding:5px;
  height:200px;
  margin-bottom:10px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
index.html:
<div id="el1" contenteditable="true">Paste here</div>
<iframe id="iframe" src="paste_iframecontent.html"></iframe>

paste_iframecontent.html:
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <div id="el2" contenteditable="true">Should go here and be logged</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I guess that the paste event from one document cannot be "redirected" into a different document. Am i right? Is there any way to get this running or to solve the "CSS style paste problem" using a different approach?